# How to use more than one explode

Tags: php, if-statement, row, explode

i actually don't have any idea how to do this, my code is this

```
$a = explode("/", $row['table']);
if(count($a)>1) {
echo implode('', $a);

}
else {
    echo $row['table'];
}
```

but, i don't want only to explode "/", i would like to explode "/", ":", "<", ">" (examples)

It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace all ":", "<" and ">" etc. with "/" and then explode "/".

```
$array = array(":", "<", ">");

foreach($array as $delimeter){
    $row['table'] = str_replace($delimeter, "/", $row['table']);
}

$a = explode("/", $row['table']);
if(count($a)>1) {
echo implode('', $a);

}
else {
    echo $row['table'];
}
```

Comment: When i use this, appears the following error:
    
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Array' (T_ARRAY)

Comment: There was an unnecessary "new" in front of Array on first line. Try again. Does it work this way?